# Issues в Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, pipelines

C Gitlab знакома недавно. Не могу найти информацию про вкладки Issues, Pipelines, Wiki. Где можно почитать на русском зачем это и как этим пользоваться. Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Во вкладке **Issues** содержится список заданий проекта (выполненных и тех, которые еще нужно выполнить); в **Pipelines** содержатся все сборки для соответствующего им коммита и результат каждого этапа последовательности развертывания; а в **Wiki** содержится мини-википедия вашего проекта (документация по нему в стиле Википедии).

Answer (score 2):

**Issues** это не задания проекта, это список  будущих нововведений, багов, и исправлений для проекта, который в добавок ко всему формируют пользователи а не только разработчики.

**Wiki** это мини-вики проекта, особенно если он большой в нём сложно сразу разобраться. Поэтому разработчики описывают там как пользоваться продуктом.

**Pipelines** это инфа о сборке проекта, мерджах и коммитах.